# CentOS 7 VirtualBox no internet access

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I am having trouble connecting my CentOS 7 guest to the internet. My VirtualBox Network configuration is as follows:

```
Adapter 1: NAT; Adapter 2: Host-Only (vboxnet0)
```

`vboxnet0` is connected set up with DHCP with default VirtualBox parameters.

In my CentOS Guest, I commanded `ip a` and got the following:

```
enp0s3: 10.0.2.15/24 (NAT adapter)
enp0s8: 192.168.56.102/24 (Host-Only adapter)
```

I can connect to my VirtualBox from my host machine:

```
ping 192.168.56.102
```

can transmit and receive packets.

However, my VirtualBox cannot access the internet:

```
ping www.google.com
```

outputs "unknown host www.google.com"

Here is my `ifcfg-enp0s3`:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=UUID HERE (sorry I cannot copy from my guest host yet, no Guest Additions and it was too long)
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

Why can't my guest connect to the internet?

Comment: in my case ( centos9),  nmcli connection up <interface name>  solved the issue.  //  nmcli connection up enp0s3.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As Gasim said:

Add the following to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
# Note this was set to no
ONBOOT=yes
```

then reboot the machine.

Comment: also reboot after these steps

Comment: Thanks, this awnser solved my problems. ONBOOT=yes did it for me, I didn't need the lines DNS1 and DNS2.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Pizey You save my day. :)

Comment: yes, as @SeanieO'Leary said. Only `ONBOOK=yes` was also needed for me.

Comment: the beauty of linux

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm

Comment: only changing to this works for me
ONBOOT=yes

Answer (score 24):

Network connection is not active by default. You can check this by running the command:

```
nmcli d
```

To edit the connection run the following command:

```
nmtui
```

1. Edit a connection
2. Choose your Ethernet connection
3. Check the option "Automatically connect" as [shown in the pic below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a7Ht.png):

   [image: nmtui GUI]
4. systemctl restart network
5. sudo shutdown -r now

Comment: This was my issue with VirtualBox and CentOS7.  Checking the "Automatically connect" option fixed my issue.  Thanks for the clear instructions...  +1

Comment: Yep! That worked like a charm.

Comment: I am unable to check the option, any idea why? Got to this screen highlighted the checkbox and clicked 'Enter' key. Still remains unchecked

Comment: @Thanthu use "Space" key to check.

Comment: In particular, this is the issue if you installed centos 7 using the text only install, which does not enable the network by default. Saved me time today, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Chances are that in `/etc/resolv.conf` you don't have any nameservers set, in which case you want to do:

`vim /etc/resolv.conf`

and add:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

save it, and once back at the shell

do:

`sudo reboot now` to reboot and you should have internet access

Comment: Adding it to resolv.conf didn't work because it was being auto generated by Network Manager, so I added `DNS1=8.8.8.8` and `DNS2=8.8.4.4` to `ifcfg-enp0s3` and it worked. But the weird thing is that, resolv.conf adds my router address as the nameserver and in my Router. My router's DNS are already Google DNS, so I don't know why it doesn't recognize the DNS when I set `nameserver 10.0.2.1` (router's address)

Comment: That was going to be my next solution

Comment: Doens't help to me

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In VirtualBox for CentOS 7 VM, I faced the same issue.

You dont need to configure these files. The DNS is set via the Network Manager. On the bottom right hand corner if you see the two monitor thingy, just right click on that and connect the network adapter.

Even though you change the resolv.conf file by adding the DNS, the DNS set at your host machine/DNS set by your service provide over rides it.

And the resolv.conf gets updated as follows -

> ## Generated by NetworkManager
>
> search XXX#.XX.comcast.net
>
> nameserver 75.75.76.76
>
> nameserver 75.75.75.75

Comment: I am not using GUI. And you can change the DNS if you change the network adapter config files. That's the proper CentOS way. That's because CentOS uses a separate network manager (I think it is called Anaconda) to automatically set IP, DNS, and other network variables for network adapters.