# Windows 7 host, CentOS guest - internet connection

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos, internet-connection

I have troubles connecting a CentOS guest on Virtualbox running on a Win 7 host.

The host has been given two adapters: Host-only and NAT.

ip a

[image]

vi 03

[image]
Note: setting `GATEWAY=10.0.2.2` still results in the same error

The /etc/resolv.conf looks ok, as in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/915536/centos-7-virtualbox-no-internet-access), that is

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

A network service restart fails with the error (as displayed by `systemctl status network.service)`Failed to start LSB: Bring ..` although killing the dhclient process as in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/660210/cant-start-centos-7-network-service) did not help.

Comment: From the manual of VirtualBox v5.0 section 9.11.1, `gateway is set to 10.0.2.2` yet you have manually set to 10.0.0.1 ?!? Have you changed the default NAT network settings for VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

If `NetworkManager` is running, it doesn't matter what you have on your `ifcg-enp0s3`, so make sure it is dead:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager 
sytemctl disable NetworkManager
ps auxww | grep NetworkManager
kill <PID> (in case it is still running)
```

After that, restart your network:

```
systemctl restart network
```

Then, check your ip address configuration

```
ifconfig
```

your gateway

```
route -n
```

and resolve any hostname to verify that you are using the DNS's you set:

```
nslookup example.com
```

---

With all this done, if it's still not working, check that the MAC address of the interface set to get the configuration via DHCP is the correct one.

Also, you are talking about the gateway but, why would you configure the network if there's a DHCP server already doing it?

I mean, when you boot up the interface, if it doesn't have any configuration, it will send a multicast `DHCP request` and the server (if it actually is on the same LAN or you are using `DHCRELAY`) will answer back with the proper settings.